# Wrong translation in the movie?

Tags: meaning-in-context, time

Recently I was watching a movie where an actor in translation (Czech dubbing) said:

> "It was the third year I was there."

But originally in English the actor said:

> "I had been there for three years."

The translation is incorrect right? Because if person had been there for three years he would have to say it was the 4th year I was there right?

Because let's say the person starts working somewhere in 2016 and 3 year passes. So it is 2019 and saying I am here the 3rd year is wrong in my opinion, isn't it?

Because the person is there already 4th year. (1st was 2016)

Comment: If you were referring to subtitles, there would simply be a question of translation accuracy.  But dubbing has a different problem.  The replacement voice needs to match pretty closely with the actor's lip movements.  They choose words of as similar a meaning as they can that can be said while passing for the actor's voice.

Answer (score 1):

Logically, you are correct.  In actual practice, the phrase "I had been there for three years" is not meant to be exact.  If I say, for example:

> I lived in Japan for two years

It doesn't necessarily mean I left the country *exactly* two years from when I arrived. The truth is I lived there for 2 years and 3 months, but "two years" is close enough for conversation.

In the same way:

> My wife and I have been married for seven years

doesn't mean that *now* is our eighth year.  Actually out anniversary is in late February, but it's close enough that "seven years" is good for casual conversation.

Of course if there was a need to be exact, I would say "**almost** seven years" or "a **little over** two years".